# Bypass template argument integer limit

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to start with template meta-programming. I wrote simple construct like this:

```
template<int N>
class Fact {
  public:
    enum { result = N * Fact<N-1>::result };
};

template<>
class Fact<0> {
  public:
    enum { result = 1 };
};
```

When I tried to call it in main like:

```
int main() {
    Fact<5> f;
    std::cout << f.result;
}
```

It works fine for smaller values of parameter. As soon as I provide bigger values like say, `15`, then compiler complains: `integer overflow in constant expression`. It appears truncation is not implicitly done by the compiler. If I revert back to smaller values and I get code to compile, then I still get warning: `variable set but unused`. Why?

Now, I made more changes to this code like:

```
template<int N>
class Fact {
  public:
    static long result;
};

template<>
class Fact<0> {
  public:
    static long result;
};

long Fact<0>::result = 1;
template<int N>
long Fact<N>::result = N * Fact<N-1>::result;
```

At this point the warning is gone, and it also seems to allow integer wrapping. I can't understand why this happens. I tried to write a vanilla class like:

```
class X{
public:
    static int d;
    enum { r = 10000000000000000l };
};

int X::d = 50;
```

And when I used it I still got the `unused` warning, and the enum also compiles. Could someone help me understand at what point in compilation stage, does template deduction happen? Why am I able to bypass compiler checks which were in place during the first case? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, the underlying type of `Fact<0>::result` is `int`.  Since your base template's `N` argument is also an `int`, the result of `N * Fact<N-1>::result` is also `int`.  That means that at `N` = `13`, the result of `N * Fact<N-1>::result` will overflow a 4-byte `int`.  Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.  Named `enum` values are compile-time constants, and undefined behavior in compile-time constant expressions is not allowed, so you get a hard error.

In your second example not only are you using `long`, which could potentially have a larger range than `int`, but `long Fact<N>::result = N * Fact<N-1>::result;` is not a compile-time constant expression.  That means that any potential undefined behavior goes undetected at compile time.  The behavior of your program is still undefined though.

The idiomatic way to make a compile-time factorial in modern C++ would be to use `constexpr` variables rather than unscoped `enum`s:

```
template<unsigned long N>
struct Fact {
    static constexpr unsigned long result = N * Fact<N-1>::result;
};

template<>
struct Fact<0> {
    static constexpr unsigned long result = 1;
};
```

Or a `constexpr` function:

```
constexpr unsigned long fact(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long ret = 1;
    for (unsigned long i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        ret *= i;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

To keep the behavior well-defined in the face of overflow, I've made the `result` members unsigned.

---

If you really need to keep compatibility with older compilers, you could add another member to your unscoped `enum` that's large enough to force its underlying type to be `unsigned long`:

```
template<unsigned long N>
struct Fact {
    enum {
        result = N * Fact<N-1>::result,
        placeholder = ULONG_MAX
    };
};

template<>
struct Fact<0> {
    enum {
        result = 1,
        placeholder = ULONG_MAX
    };
};
```

Note that I used `ULONG_MAX` instead of `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max()` since the latter is only a compile-time constant expression in C++11 or later, and the only reason I can think of to use this approach is to maintain compatibility with pre-C++11 compilers.

Comment: Other alternative for compatibility since C++11, is to provide underlying type of the enum: `enum : unsigned long {/*..*/};`.

Comment: And notice that constexpr function doesn't guaranty constexpr evaluation: `std::cout << fact(5)` would be computed at runtime (but optimizer would probably succeed to resolve the constant).So adding extra layer with constexpr variable might be good to enforce compile time evaluation.

Comment: I didn't know about enum: type, it's a cool trick! I agree about the constexpr function. I was just experimenting around with template deductions, so I wanted the compile-time variable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of int or **long** you can use the type **long long**.

```
class Fact {
public:
    enum: long long { result = N * Fact<N - 1>::result };
};

template<>
class Fact<0> {
public:
    enum : long long { result = 1 };
};
```

But even **long long** can be overflown. In assembler there is an overflow flag. But in C++ you can use a trick, if the result is smaller than initial value then an overflown occurred during addition or multiplication.

Comment: I got it about the overflow, my objective was to find out if I could somehow bypass the overflow check as in the case of compile-time constants. This is solved by constexpr, as explained in the answer.

Comment: @user2338150 Just curious. Why would you need to bypass suppress a warning about a number that is wrong by definition? Are you doing some special big number maths?

Comment: Oh, no no, it's just for experimentation sake. Compile-time constants can't be wrong by definition: in a way it is like an assertion except breaching it causes hard compile time error. On run-time constructs attempted by me, there was no way for the compiler to know what I intended to do. If I were trying some large number math, I'd not rely on signed overflow, which is documented as undefined behavior. But, I'm just a novice! :)